# How to resume interrupted download in i.files app

Tags: applications, iphone

I have installed i.files app version 1.6 for iphone. In description of this app in app store has been written it can resume download from broken point, now i have tried to download 2 or 3 files with this app, when download was interrupted and we click start , it start download from first start point.
Please help how this app works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No one can really answer this question except the developer, it will just be opinion based. So here is my opinion:*

This is a developer issue, you can review the app and tell them about this bug. This app doesn't have a support page in English so I doubt you will get support from them directly.

Here is an alternative app that can resume downloads:

[Downloads Free](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/downloads-free/id475190096?mt=8) | [Downloads](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/downloads/id463169954?mt=8)

Please note that this app can not save video files any more, that's why the current version has 1 star rating. But other than that, it's perfect! :)